# Replace All Lines That Do Not Contain Matched String

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm working with this file of data that looks like this:

```
text in file
hello random text in file
example text in file
words in file hello
more words in file
hello text in file can be
more text in file
```

I'm trying to replace all lines that do *not* contain the string `hello` with `match` using sed, so the output would be:

```
match
hello random text in file
match
words in file hello
match
hello text in file can be
match
```

I tried using `sed '/hello/!d'` but that deletes the line. Also, I read that I can match using `!` within sed but I'm not sure how to match every line and replace properly. If you could give me some direction, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$ sed '/hello/!s/.*/match/' infile
match
hello random text in file
match
words in file hello
match
hello text in file can be
match
```

`/hello/!` makes sure we're substituting only on lines not containing `hello` (you had that right), and the substitution then replaces the complete pattern space (`.*`) with `match`.

Comment: definitely way to go, brilliant answer

Answer (score 8):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!/hello/{$0="match"}1' file
```

replace the lines not matching "hello" with "match" and print all lines.

Comment: Hey Karakfa, this is good but is removes other lines in addition to replacing the line.

Comment: it shouldn't, `1` is there to print all lines.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Thank you. I'm not too good with awk but this works great.

Answer (score 6):

Sed with the `c` (change) command:

```
$ sed '/hello/!c match' file
match
hello random text in file
match
words in file hello
match
hello text in file can be
match
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk for clarity, simplicity, etc.:

```
awk '{print (/hello/ ? $0 : "match")}' file
```